# Django: Change value in request.POST to 0 if empty

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following form:

[image]

When one of the tickets is empty, my form sends me an error with that every field is required, now I am trying to check if the form value is empty, if it's empty I want to change it to `0`, so `form.is_valid()` can be true.

The attached code doesn't work. It says `string index out of range`.

```
   def reserve_ticket(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            quantities = request.POST.getlist('quantity')

            for i in range(len(quantities)):
                if not request.POST['quantity'][i]:
                    request.POST['quantity'][i] = 0

            form = ReserveForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                print("Hello world")
                return HttpResponse("Hello world")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Back to homepage")
```

Comment: why would you do it ? I think you should rethink the logic of your view

Comment: My view is a DetailView with a form in it. This form is sent to the function above (reserve_ticket(request)), which should then enter the data in the database. I tried to change the model to default = 0, but this didn't work as I am creating the form manually.

Comment: You could perform `clean_`ing in the `Form` and change the empty string to `0`.

Comment: `request.POST['quantity']` will return a string or give  a `KeyError`. It doesn't make sense to try to replace `request.POST['quantity'][i]` (one of the characters of the string) with an integer `0`.

Comment: @Alasdair: well as far as I know, it is not even possible, since `request.POST` itself is immutable, and strings are immutable as well :).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you can create a mutable copy of `request.POST` with the [`copy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.copy) method. It's trying to modify the string that really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's not very clean to try to alter the post data. Instead, make the field optional in your form with `required=False` (or `blank=True` in the model field) so that there aren't form errors when the field is missing.

If it's a model form, you could set a default value on the field. Or, for a regular form you could override `clean_<fieldname>` and return `0` when the value isn't specified.

Comment: I tried it with quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0) in the models, that's what you meant right? Problem is, that the default = 0 didn't help to remove the error.

Comment: @JonProgrammer: you also need to specify `required=False` in the form then, since otherwise, default is *never* used.

Comment: `default=0` is the second part of the answer. The first part is to make the field optional in the form with `required=False`, or in the model with `blank=True`.

Comment: Okay blank=True was a very good point. I didn't have this. Now my only issue is once I access form.cleaned_data['ticket'] I actually expected three tickets ['Early Bird', 'Regular Ticket', 'Last Minute Ticket'] however I only see 'Early Bird'. Is that for the reason that I created my form manually? I gave every field the name 'ticket'. I guess the only way to fix that is a model form in my DetailView..

Comment: I can't answer that because you haven't shown your form or view. It sounds like an unrelated issue so really belongs on a different question.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will look into it again and try to solve with the new information I have now.